# First order ODE from Michaelis–Menten kinetics

Tags: differential-equations

From [Michaelis-Menten kinetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) one could easily derive scalar first-order differential equation
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = A_0 + A_1 x + A_2 y + B \frac{y}{x},$$
where
$A_0, A_1, A_2, B$ are some constants, that depend on rates of reactions.

I'm interested if there are any mathematical facts, that known for this type of equation.
I doubt that it is possible to find explicit analytical solution in elementary functions. Also I see that this type of equation doesn't admit nonlinear superposition (unlike Riccati equation, for example).

Comment: I guess, we could re-write the scheme of reactions in a linear-algebraic style for initial condition and deal with eigenvectors/eigenvalues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain (see "Chemistry"-> Michaelis-Menten on that page).

Answer (score 1):

Maple classifies this as an Abel equation of type 2A.  It can also be considered as a Chini equation with $n=-1$.  The Chini invariant depends on $x$ (except in trivial cases: $A_0 = A_2 = 0$), so this does not lead to a closed-form solution.  Moreover, Maple's **symgen** finds no symmetries.

There are some rather special cases with particular solutions.  Thus
$x = - A_2 y/A_1 $ is a solution if $B={\frac {{A_2}\, \left( {A_0}\,{ A_1}+{ A_2} \right) }{{{
 A_1}}^{2}}}
$

Comment: In quasisteady approximation (that is surely simplification of initial system of Michaelis-Menten) one has to involve Lambert-W function to get exact solution. I'm pretty sure without special function there is no chance to get closed-form solution for this equation...

Comment: If LambertW was all that was needed to express a solution, Maple would be likely to find such a solution.  But it does not.